# Update pin to keyboard after autorotation on iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, keyboard, autolayout, autorotate

I have working code that pins UI to keyboard height when it appears:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    self.bottomSpacing.constant = kbSize.height + 10;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.bottomSpacing.constant = 10;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

But it has issue when device autorotates: keyboard height changes (ex. on iPad 313 => 398) and 'bottomSpacing' becomes outdated.

How to update it to new keyboard height? Alternatively, is it possible to assign autolayout constraint to keyboard view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to listen to `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillResize:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];

...

- (void)keyboardWillResize:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    float keyboardTop = CGRectGetMinY([info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue]);
    float animationDuration = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue];

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
        self.pinToKeyboardConstraint.constant = keyboardTop;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

This notification fires whenever the keyboard changes bounds including show and hide events.